# How can I change required layout when user clicks on button then add item button has to appear in Flutter

Tags: flutter, shopping-cart, provider, state-management

I am new to Flutter state management. I want the same functionality according to this video. https://streamable.com/6zm375?src=player-page-share. When the user clicks on button then add ttems button has to display and we can add items.

Here is the code of this "ADD" widget.

```
Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, top: 50,),
     child: SizedBox(
     width: 102,
     height: 58,
     child: Container(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                      
     border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
     color: Colors.white,
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6), 
    ),
    child: 
   const Center(
   child: Text('Add', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, 
   color: Color(0XFFDF2C25)),)),
   ),
  //child: Icon(CupertinoIcon),
   ),
   ),
```

Comment: Please use normal capitalization when writing titles and body text of questions. That is, capitalize the first letter of a sentence, I (first person singular), and proper names, everything else should be lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same by using ValueNotifier in Flutter.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-ZG-jS5QHQ

Create a ValueNotifier named as `cartItems`

`final ValueNotifier<int> cartItems = ValueNotifier<int>(0);`

Whenever you click on Add Button update the value of `cartItems` by using `cartItems.value=cartItems.value+1;`

And you can wrap your bottom bar's count widget with ValueListenableBuilder for `cartItems` valueNotifier, which will update the count UI whenever the `cartItems` value changes.

For More:
https://medium.flutterdevs.com/exploring-valuelistenablebuilder-in-flutter-9a16fc4c4c5b

```
final ValueNotifier<int> cartItems = ValueNotifier<int>(0);

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Dummy"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
          valueListenable: cartItems,
          builder: (context, value, child) => Text("$value"),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          cartItems.value = cartItems.value + 1;
        },
        icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```